# java program to sort the airline based on the carrier cost

Tags: arrays, sorting

The requirement is to get the user input of the airline and their rates. then we have to display the combined array sorted based on the rates of the airline.

For example:
The below entries are user input in the form of array which would vary in number and description as per the need of the user. The input array would merge and get sorted

Enter the list of carrier:

```
Air India
Lufthansa
Emirates
Etihad
British Airways
```

Enter the cost:

```
500
350
400
550
450
```

Output:

```
Lufthansa-350
Emirates-400
British Airways-450
Air India-500
Emirates-550
```

That is the combined array would be sorted based on the cost of the carrier.
My Code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]){

        // fill the code
        int n,i,temp;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        n = sc.nextInt();
        int a[] = new int[n];
        String b[] = new String[n]; 
        for (i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            b[i] = sc.next();
        }
        for (i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
          a[i] = sc.nextInt();  
        }
        for (i=0;i<n;i++)
        {

        System.out.println("Details are :"+(b[i]+"-"+a[i]));
      }
       for ( i = 0; i < n; i++) 
        {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++) 
            {
                if ((a[i]) > (a[j]))
                {
                    temp = (a[i]);
                    (a[i]) = (a[j]);
                    (a[j]) = temp;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Sorted are :"+(b[i]+"-"+a[i]));
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Jaydip, Could you please help me in this requirement please?

Answer (score 2):

```
import java.util.*;

public class Mapp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Map<Integer,String> mp=new TreeMap<>();
        mp.put(500,"Air India");
        mp.put(350,"Lufthansa");
        mp.put(400,"Emirates");
        mp.put(550,"Etihad");
        mp.put(450,"British Airways");

         Set mapset=mp.entrySet();
         System.out.println(mp);
    }

}
```

> In case if you want user to input values

:     import java.util.*;

```
public class Mapp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Map<Integer,String> mp=new TreeMap<>();
        System.out.println("Enter number of Entries: ");
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        int et=0;
        et=sc.nextInt();
        while(et!=0)
       {
          System.out.println("Enter Cost");
         int cost=0;
         Scanner cst=new Scanner(System.in);
         cost=cst.nextInt();
         System.out.println("Enter Airline Service");
         Scanner name=new Scanner(System.in);
         String nm=null;
         nm=name.nextLine();
         mp.put(cost,nm);
         et--;
       }


         Set mapset=mp.entrySet();
         System.out.println(mp);
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi Andrew,Thanks for the response

Comment: Hopefully my answer served your answer. If so accept it please.

Comment: Hi Andrew, The string and integer are not displayed as array. The string and integer array would be merged together and then sorted as per the value. Could you please help me in this?

Comment: what you mean by displayed as an array? Give me an example